# whole post acts as "click to refresh" button

Tags: bug, live-refresh

[image: gif of behaviour]

I have been getting this quite annoying behaviour today where when a post is updated while I am on the same page instead of the usual "an edit was made, click to refresh" button at the top it seems the entire post functioned as that button.  Where clicking anywhere on the post  - including the share, edit and flag buttons - refreshes the post.  This is fixed by refreshing the page in the web browser but when a thread is being constantly edited it can become very annoying.

I am using safari for mac and haven't tested this on other browsers yet.

Comment: _"and haven't tested this on other browsers yet"_ Behaves the same recently with other browsers unfortunately. A page refresh fixes that as a workaround for me.

Comment: I have noticed that same behaviour myself in the past week or so and now today.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ The page refresh works but is more of a client-side fix rather than a serverside. I hope they've also noticed this behaviour and looking to fix it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- As mentioned, it's a _workaround_.